# How to get the tk/tcl libraries and .h files (win)

Tags: c++, tcl, mingw, tk-toolkit

I want to use the C++/Tk library for a project.(https://cpptk.sourceforge.net/index.html)

I managed to setup the boost library but I still need the tcl and tk libraries and tcl.h and tk.h for it. (https://www.tcl.tk/)

It's a uni project so I'm stuck to work with codeblocks and the Mingw compiler on windows.

I tried it with the "tcl8613-src.zip" and "tk8613-src.zip" and I assume the content in the "win" folder are relevant for me. But I don't know what to do from there on

Comment: If it's a uni project, they should give you guide learning materials and build environment setup. Use pacman package manager and install tcl https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-tcl and tk https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-tk

Comment: Related to the above comment. See if its permitted to use msys2 to provide your MinGW. If so installing open source libraries with msys2 is easy because it has a package manager `pacman` which has thousands of open source libraries in its repository. You can setup Code::Blocks to use the MinGW that msys2 provides.

Comment: I'm not sure if mingw has the ability to run the configure script in the `win` or if you need msys2 for that (which definitely can do it). Once you have done that, your tools will probably be able to make a build.